# Does not insert as a new record instead replaces a previous record

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have tried to insert a new record in the database table instead this keeps replacing the record in the table. (Currently i have a single record in this table). Any ideas why? Here's my query:

```
public function setExperimentData($name, $type, $description) {
    $updateQuery = $this->repository->createQueryBuilder('ud')
        ->update()
        ->set('ud.name', $this->em->createQueryBuilder()->expr()->literal($name))
        ->set('ud.type', $this->em->createQueryBuilder()->expr()->literal($type))
        ->set('ud.description', $this->em->createQueryBuilder()->expr()->literal($description))                                      
        ->getQuery();
    $updateQuery->execute();
}
```

---

Yes i have tried the following (Experiments() is the entity):

```
$experiment = new Experiments();
$experiment->setName($experimentName);        
$experiment->setDescription($experimentDescription);
$experiment->setPrimaryinvestigator($primaryInvestigator);
```

Then i get the following error:

Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Test\HelloBundle\Entity\Experiments::setPrimaryinvestigator() must be an instance of Test\HelloBundle\Entity\Users

Here is my setter for primary investigator in the entity class:

```
public function setPrimaryinvestigator(\Test\HelloBundle\Entity\Users $primaryinvestigator = null)
    {
        $this->primaryinvestigator = $primaryinvestigator;

        return $this;
    }
```

What am i doing wrong?

UPDATE:

Its an integer passed.E,g, 1 is the id of the PrimaryInvestigator.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think the QueryBuilder supports insert queries at this time. Assuming you have an Experiment entity with setters, have you tried

```
public function setExperimentData($name, $type, $description) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $experiment = new Experiment();
    $experiment->setName($name);
    $experiment->setType($type);
    $experiment->setDescription($description);
    $em->persist($experiment);
    $em->flush();
}
```

Comment: mattexx check the below post.